# Can't set image display 'block' using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html element:

```
<img id="loader" src="../Images/ajax-loader-white.gif" alt="process..." style="width: 50px; height: 50px; display: none;" />
```

I try to change display property with help of jquery:

```
$('#loader').attr('style').attr('display') = 'block';
```

But in error above I get error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).attr is not a function

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `show()` method like following.

```
$('#loader').show()
```

or `css()` method like following.

```
$('#loader').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery show method to show an element

```
 $('#loader').show() //or $('#loader').fadeIn()
```

You can also hide using following

```
 $('#loader').hide()
```